How to edit DITA link in OxygenXML Author mode
In the Author Mode of OxygenXML it's quite easy to insert a new link (cross-reference), from the DITA toolbar or menu.
But, it appears the only way to edit an existing link (without resorting to attributes) is to first remove the link from the text [1], and then re-generate it.
Is there a simpler way of changing the linked target for a DITA xref?
[1] Which itself is counter-intuitive, performed by putting the cursor immediately to the right of the link icon, then press back-space.

We do not have an explicit "Edit Link" functionality in Oxygen for DITA XML editing. So as you said, you can either use the Attributes view or the in-place Attributes editing dialog, or unwrap the link text using backspace on the link start tag or by using the contextual menu "Refactoring->Delete Element Tags" and then insert the link again.

Note: in DITA mode, I see that option under "Markup > Delete Element Tags".
This approach is particularly good, since the user can use the Cross Reference dialog, which leads them through choosing a target anchor (if relevant).
